# What does "come away" mean here, in reference to a memorial?

Tags: meaning, phrasal-verbs

Does *come away* here mean "you come away from home"?

From a [CNN article](http://edition.cnn.com/2011/US/08/31/911.memorial/index.html?&hpt=hp_c1):

> Robert Henry, a former U.S. appeals judge whose office was across the street from the federal building, says the memorial tells the story of a community that pulls together—and a country that does not forget its people.
>
> "You ***come away*** seeing the greatness of a federal republic at its best," said Henry, now president of Oklahoma City University. "At the bombing, we came together."

Answer (score 3):

To [come away](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/come) (from something) means

> to leave a place with a particular feeling or impression

As @Thursagen points out, Henry is saying that when you leave the memorial, you have the impression described, of "the greatness of a federal republic at its best".

Answer (score 2):

Robert Henry was not meaning that we come away from home, but rather, you come away from the memorial, seeing the greatness of a federal republic at its best.

He was implying that you've already visited it, and now, you are coming away, after seeing etc.

The article was about Oklahoma City, that got bombed, and 168 people died. A memorial was set up remembering these people. It is an act of admirable bravery, and community spirit.